# AWS Public DNS does not load even though SSH works

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have set up an AWS EC2 Instance with LAMP stack and installed Wordpress.

My instance was accessible through a browser via its public DNS. I logged into wordpress admin and made some changes and everything was working ok.

I then added an Elastic IP and I now cannot access my site through a browser via its public DNS.

However, the server is fully accessible via SSH.

The public DNS is:

[ec2-52-210-2-56.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com][1]

My security groups are as follows:

80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0
22  tcp 209.93.74.222/32
443 tcp 0.0.0.0/0

I have removed the EIP. That made no difference. I have rebooted and stopped and restarted the instance. That made no difference either.

I am not sure how to fix it?

Comment: can you paste what apache config you have set

Comment: Not sure how to get that info? Can I use a simple SSH command?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of apache when I set up the instance. httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd.

Comment: Is your DB local or you using RDS?

Comment: Using local DB not RDS

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when i was new to AWS figuring out new things.

What i found out was you need to perform the below steps to redirect your url to correct IP address:

The old site URL and the new site URL for your instance. The old site URL is likely the public DNS name for your EC2 instance when you installed WordPress. The new site URL is the current public DNS name for your EC2 instance. If you are not sure of your old site URL, you can use curl to find it with the following command.

```
$curl localhost | grep wp-content
```

You should see references to your old public DNS name in the output, which will look like this (old site URL in red):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ec2-52-8-139-223.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/functions.js?ver=20150330'></script>


$ curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
```

Search and replace the old site URL in your WordPress installation with the following command. Substitute the old and new site URLs for your EC2 instance and the path to your WordPress installation (usually /var/www/html or /var/www/html/blog).

```
$ php wp-cli.phar search-replace 'old_site_url' 'new_site_url' --path=/path/to/wordpress/installation --skip-columns=guid
```

Your website will be fixed!!!
Done!

**NOTE:** But everytime you change the IP you need to change your url to new IP.

Comment: `curl localhost | grep wp-content` does not print the old URL. I only prints:

Comment: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0

Comment: you can find the wp-content in your Wordpress folder(/var/www/html/wordpress)...try to tweak it manually

Answer (score 0):

Visit [This site can’t be reached Amazon Ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620719/this-site-can-t-be-reached-amazon-ec2/52847570#52847570)

I got the issue with Windows EC2 while connecting through HTTP 80 port and followed below link.

If your computer is on a corporate network, ask your network administrator whether the internal firewall allows inbound and outbound traffic from your computer on port 22 (for Linux instances) or port 3389 (for Windows instances).

If you have a firewall on your computer, verify that it allows inbound and outbound traffic from your computer on port 22 (for Linux instances) or port 3389 (for Windows instances).

or follow link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout

Check Firewall settings in your Windows EC2: Goto > Firewall Settings or Properties choose public profile > check inbound connections, change to "Allow" if it is "Blocked by default"